# In App Purchase sanbox reopens repeatedly and does not send purchased status in stream

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I am facing a weird issue while making a purchase of auto renewable subscription through in_app_purchase package in IOS simulator 17.0.

Here is the preview of the issue:
https://www.loom.com/share/0a483d3dcba44807bec0a38e0a752e66?sid=faf18c39-f93f-47a0-8ed2-fc4e867c99b2

What works well:

1. I am able to fetch my subscription product from the app store.

```
Future<void> _getProducts() async { ProductDetailsResponse response = await _iap.queryProductDetails(productIds.toSet()); if (response.notFoundIDs.isNotEmpty) { print('These products were not found: ${response.notFoundIDs.join(', ')}'); } _products = response.productDetails; notifyListeners();   }
```

2. I am able to open the sandbox and start the pruchase using sanbox tester account in the apple app store.

```
    Future<void> buyProduct(ProductDetails product) async { final PurchaseParam purchaseParam = PurchaseParam(productDetails: product); try { await _iap.buyNonConsumable(purchaseParam: purchaseParam); } catch (e) { print("$e"); }   }
```

3. The sanbox shows the "DONE" UI, but I NEVER get the PurchasedStatus.purchased in my stream, and the sandbox reopens again.

The cycle repeats

Here is the output of my flutter doctor -v

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.1, on macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
• Flutter version 3.13.1 on channel stable at /Users/muhammadhamadjamal/Documents/FlutterDev/sdk/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision e1e4722 (3 months ago), 2023-08-22 21:43:18 -0700
• Engine revision b20183e040
• Dart version 3.1.0
• DevTools version 2.25.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
• Android SDK at /Users/muhammadhamadjamal/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.2
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 15A240d
• CocoaPods version 1.13.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.84.1)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.76.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
• iPhone 15 Pro Max (mobile) • DC9EDD04-0B17-4D27-BD2A-966F06BFCF7F • ios •
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-17-0 (simulator)
• macOS (desktop) • macos • darwin-x64 • macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-x64
• Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 119.0.6045.105

[✓] Network resources
• All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!

Comment: Same issue here, have you been able to solve this ?

Comment: I was not using Storekit configuration. It seems, the purchase does not work on simulator except local storekit config done through xcode @Paolo